# How to change the expiration time of a Google Access Token?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

I have this code to authenticate the user using oauth 2.0 api in php but I want to change the expiry time of the token usually the token expires in 1 hour but I have to change it to the maximum time I think it is 200 days. how can I achieve that. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated

```
<?php
  class Connection {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->credentials = "credentials.json";
        $this->client = $this->create_client();
    }

    public function get_client() {
      return $this->client;
    }

    public function get_credentials() {
      return $this->credentials;
    }

    public function is_connected() {
      return $this->is_connected;
    }

    public function get_unauthenticated_data() {
      $authUrl = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
      return "<a href='$authUrl'>Click here to link your account</a>";
    }

    public function credentials_in_browser() {
      if ($_GET['code']) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }

    public function create_client() {
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setApplicationName('Gmail API PHP');
      $client->addScope('https://mail.google.com/');
      $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
      $client->setAccessType('offline');
      $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
      $tokenPath = 'token.json';
      if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
          $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
          $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
      }

      if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
          if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
              $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
          } elseif($this->credentials_in_browser()) {
            $authCode = $_GET['code'];
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
          } else {
            $this->is_connected = false;
            return $client;
          }
          if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
              mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
          }
          file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
      }
      else {}

      $this->is_connected = true;
      return $client;
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Oauth2.

Access tokens by standard expire after one hour.  This is configured by the authorization server that created it.  So if you own the authorization server that created it you would have access to change the expiration time.

Google Access tokens are created by Googles authorization server, Googles access tokens expire after one hour.  You do not have access to change this.

That being said.

Your code appears to be using offline access and using the refresh token to request a new access token.

```
if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
          $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
```

Refresh tokens are long lived as long as your application is in set to production your refresh token should not expire.  Your code will then request a new access token when ever it needs one.

So technically you dont need to set the access token to 200 days, your refresh token should already be longer then that.

Note with the gmail api refresh tokens will expire if the user changes their password.

Comment: But sir I want to change the expiry time in this way like if the expiry of token is 1 hour I want it to set to 30 min. Is this is possible??

Comment: No ma'am it is not possible, unless you own the authorization server.

Comment: @HIMANSHUSINGH  As far as I know, there is no way to "set" the specific time to it. If you wanna make your token to be expired, just request another one, then the first token will be expired. So maybe, write a timer to request a new token every 30 mins. Hope this will help your request.

Comment: @BobTheCat if your want to verify your statement rather than just saying **as far as i know** You can consult [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.2.2) this section describes how access tokens are intended to work.   TBH in the future if you dont personally know the answer its best not to comment, as miss information may cloud the issue and confuse people.  Welcome to stack Overflow.

Comment: @BobTheCat  **So maybe, write a timer to request a new token every 30 mins.** In the case of a some Authorization servers this may not work some may just return to you the same token they gave you the first time.   If you read the question the author wants his tokens to last 200 days not 30 minutes so really your statement will not help them as by design the access token will expire after 3600 seconds or one hour.

Comment: @DaImTo Nice document. basically, my answer is base on my experience. Here is the document I use to implement google oauth2.0  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Comment: @BobTheCat  Have you checked the link in the first line from the page you just linked  **Google APIs use the [OAuth 2.0 protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749) for authentication and authorization.**   They follow industry standard of 3600.